# weird behaviour with jquery click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing a custom radio element who displays images instead of regular radio.

Basic html is like :

```
<div id="wrap">
   <p></p>
   <input type="radio" data-check='class-check' data-uncheck='class-uncheck' style='display:none;'>
   <p></p>
   <input type="radio" data-check='class-check' data-uncheck='class-uncheck' style='display:none;'>
   <p></p>
   <input type="radio" data-check='class-check' data-uncheck='class-uncheck' style='display:none;'>
</div>
```

to create custom radio :

```
$("#wrap").radio({someData});
```

I successfuly create the elements I need and images are displayed, I just have some problems with the click event (part of the code):

```
var elems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
    elems.push({});


    elems[i].input = $(this).find("input").eq(i);                 // get input
    $("<div></div>").insertAfter(elems[i].input);                 // create a div to display image to
    elems[i].wrap = elems[i].input.next();
    elems[i].wrap.click(function(elem){
        console.log(elem);                                        // this console.log is triggered when the page load, not on click event
        elem.addClass('img-checked').removeClass('img-uncheked'); // only the last element in elems have its class changed, not the elems[i] I give as parameter.
    }(elems[i]));
}
```

I dont understund why the `console.log` is triggered on script load and not on click event.

Also the `console.log` display the good data but the class change only apply on the last element of `elems[i]` when click is triggered.

I also tried without giving any parameters to `click` function and just use `elems[i]` directly but it acts the same, always applying changes on the last entry of `elems`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I dont understund why the console.log is triggered on script load and not on click event.

Because you are **executing** the function immediately.

```
elems[i].wrap.click(function(elem){
    console.log(elem);                                     
    elem.addClass('img-checked').removeClass('img-uncheked');
}(elems[i]));
```

See the `(elems[i])` at the end? That calls the function and passes its *return value* to `.click`. It might be more obvious what you are doing if you define the function separately:

```
function foo(elem){
    console.log(elem);                                     
    elem.addClass('img-checked').removeClass('img-uncheked');
}
elems[i].wrap.click(foo(elems[i]));
```

It should be clearer now why `console.log` is called on page load.

---

If you want to capture the the current element, I suggest to use pass `elems[i]` as [`event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/):

```
elems[i].wrap.click(elems[i], function(event){
    console.log(event.data);    
    // elem / event.data is not a jQuery object, so I don't know which element 
    // you wanted to target here
    elem.addClass('img-checked').removeClass('img-uncheked');
});
```

If you look at the [jQuery documentation for `.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), you can see that it accepts an optional `eventData` argument, which will be made available to the event handler as `event.data`.

Comment: I didn't know we could give parameters that way. I tried it work. I love you. I valid as soon as I can. Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
 elems[i].wrap.click(function(elem){
        console.log(elem);                                        // this console.log is triggered when the page load, not on click event
        elem.addClass('img-checked').removeClass('img-uncheked'); // only the last element in elems have its class changed, not the elems[i] I give as parameter.
    }(elems[i]));
```

basically click function's parameter denote event. again you are passing a element as click function's parameter but click takes a function pointer. you dont need to pass the element. you can access element by $(this)

so change it by

```
elems[i].wrap.click(function(event){
        console.log($(this));                                        // this console.log is triggered when the page load, not on click event
        $(this).addClass('img-checked').removeClass('img-uncheked'); // only the last element in elems have its class changed, not the elems[i] I give as parameter.
    });
```

Comment: The problem is that I need a bunch of option contained in `elems`. I have to access these option inside the click function so `this` isn't enough. "I also tried without giving any parameters to click function and just use elems[i] directly but it acts the same, always applying changes on the last entry of elems"